# Android Read Data Json Object

Tags: android, json, serialization

My JSON

```
[{
"id": 1,
"media": {
    "name": "ABC",
    "url": "abc.org/"
},
"published": "2016-01-24T16:00:00.000Z",
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "acb.net"
    }
}
}]
```

This is my Code

```
public class Channel {

   @SerializedName("id")
   private String mId;

   @SerializedName("media")
   // ????????????

   @SerializedName("published")
   private String mPublished;

   @SerializedName("_links")
   // ????????????
   }
```

Please. Help me read data at `@SerializedName("media")` and   `@SerializedName("_links")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new Model class like this:

```
public class Media {

 @SerializedName("name")
 private String name;

 @SerializedName("url")
 private String url;

}
```

And then in your Channel class you should map it like this:

```
public class Channel {

 @SerializedName("id")
 private String mId;

 @SerializedName("media")
 private Media mMedia;

}
```

And do the same for _links. Create a model name Links or whatever name you like and map it the same way like Media.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I will try it .!